# Generic PHP MySQL connection class

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, database-connection

Are there any great, lightweight MySQL connection classes out there for PHP that anyone recommends?

I have written my own, and I do think it is pretty good but this seems like the sort of thing that many programmers better than me must have perfected long ago.

I'm interested in finding something that I can slot in generically and use as I need it with as little hassle as possible.

Some generic functions to support querying, connecting to multiple MySQL databases within the one application would also be a plus.

Comment: I am happy with just one function and no classes nor multiple connect support. It's all seems overkill to me

Comment: What's wrong with `ext/mysqli` (apart from messy prepared statements API)?

Answer (score 4):

Have you had a look at PDO? http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 2):

PHP's PDO (PHP Data Objects) extension is my recommendation.  I use it alongside a light-weight database class that extends PDO.  You can find this open-source project on Google's Project Hosting at http://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class.

Answer (score 1):

A class of my own invention: [DB](http://github.com/nikic/DB)

It may be called very lightweight (less than 100 lines of code). It is a wrapper around [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and it actually only adds a very handy way of escaping variables and a short syntax (`DB::query()` instead of `DB::instance()->query()`.)

But this short syntax results in it being limited to once connection.

Answer (score 1):

this is a very neat and easy to use class: http://justinvincent.com/ezsql

wordpress database class is also derived from the above class

Comment: links to site about blenders. spam?

Comment: @juggleware
LOL looks like Justin Vincent doesnt own that domain now, so I have updated the link. You should probably have checked my profile and the cached version of the page, before marking it as spam. I am not supposed to update links if the author chooses to disown a domain :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and lightweight db class is

http://code.google.com/p/edb-php-class/

```
<?php
$result = $db->q("select * from `users`limit 3");

foreach($result as $a){
        $a = (object) $a;
        echo $a->id.' '.$a->name.' '.$a->url.' '.$a->img.'</br>';
}


$result = $db->line("select * from `users` where id = '300' limit 1");
echo $result['name']; 
echo $result['surname']; 



$name = $db->one("select name from `ilike_pics` where id = '300' limit 1");
echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

May try [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) and [ADOdb Lite](http://adodblite.sourceforge.net/)